# How to automatically submit a form in vue-cli?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vue-cli

I want to submit a hidden form when the page loads. Since the form is hidden, I can’t use a submit button. So how can I automatically submit a form when the page loads in vuejs?

```
<template>
  <div v-html="this.paymentResponse"></div>
</template>

<script>
import EventBus from '../../event-bus'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            paymentResponse: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('mounted')
        this.$refs.submitBtn.click();
    },  
    beforeCreate() {
        EventBus.$on("payment", response => {
            this.paymentResponse = response
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question could use more details. Consider explaining what it is you are trying to do. That will help determine if what you are looking for is a form submission, or if some other form of AJAX call might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the submit button on `mounted` as follows:

```js
new Vue({
     el: '#sg1',
     mounted(){
          this.$refs.submitBtn.click();
     },
     methods:{
          formSumitted(){
               console.log("submitted");
          }
     }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="sg1">
    <form style="display:none" v-on:submit.prevent="formSumitted">
         <button type="submit" ref="submitBtn">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Since the form is passed and rendered using `v-html`, I don't think you can use `ref`. Therefore, you can replace it with the `id` and use vanillla Javascript function to click the button:

```
document.getElementById("submitBtn").click();
```

Comment: How can I do this in vue-cli?

Comment: Can you explain more? It's the same thing, add the code in the component containing the form.

Comment: There's a page called checkout.vue. A post request is sent to the server from this page and the response is an html form. This html form is passed to a new page using event bus and on the new page, the html form is rendered in the created hook. The button click is called in the mounted hook but it's not working.

Comment: I have attached the code snippet above. console.log() in the mounted hook is working but `this.$refs.submitBtn.click();` is not working

Comment: I tried it. but it's not working. I am getting the following error `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null"`

Comment: Make sure to get the line executed after the setting of the variable and rendering of html. Perhaps you can put them all in mounted...

Comment: it finally worked. In order to make sure to get the line executed after the setting of the variable and rendering of HTML, I used a set timeout function.

Comment: ```mounted() {
        EventBus.$on("payment", response => {
            this.paymentResponse = response
        })
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById('submitBtn').click();
        }, 3000);
    }```

Answer (score -2):

The vue components have a lifeCycle, you can use the methods "created" or "mounted" for submit your form at the begining, when your app start.

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    formData: 'some data'
  },
  created: function () {
    // here your code for submit the form
    
  }
})
```